# change the text of show/hide and initially show

Tags: javascript

I have this code which works good: and i do not want to use jquery to it, because jquery is kind of overkill here for this small function

```
function showHide(targetName) {
    if( document.getElementById ) { // NS6+
        target = document.getElementById(targetName);
    } else if( document.all ) { // IE4+
        target = document.all[targetName];
    }

    if( target ) {
        if( target.style.display == "none" ) {
            target.style.display = "inline";

        } else {
            target.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}

<a href="javascript:showHide('stackbox')">Stack Trace (click to expand)</a>
```

i want to change its behaviour to initially as show and label to be shown as :

```
<a href="javascript:showHide('stackbox')">Stack Trace (click to collapse)</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `textContent` of the link when it is clicked based on whether of not `#stackbox` is hidden.

```html
<a href="javascript:showHide('stackbox')" id="link">Stack Trace (click to collapse)</a>
<p/>
<span id="stackbox">Stack trace...</span>
<script>
function showHide(targetName) {
var elem = document.getElementById("link");
    if( document.getElementById ) { // NS6+
        target = document.getElementById(targetName);
    } else if( document.all ) { // IE4+
        target = document.all[targetName];
    }

    if( target ) {
        if( target.style.display == "none" ) {
            target.style.display = "inline";
            elem.textContent = "Stack Trace (click to collapse)"

        } else {
            target.style.display = "none";
            elem.textContent = "Stack Trace (click to expand)";
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: your code does not work, it just changes the text, does not open the panel actually

Answer (score 0):

use "target.innerText" as bellow:

```
    if( target ) {
    if( target.style.display == "none" ) {
        target.style.display = "inline";
        target.innerText = "Stack Trace (click to collapse)";
    } else {
        target.style.display = "none";
        target.innerText = "Stack Trace (click to expand)";
    }
}
```